# Eclipse 4 RCP Disable Part Switch

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, e4

In my (pure) E4 App I want to force the User to enter something in a [Text Field](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html) before he can move on.

Currently, if nothing has been entered into the [Text Field](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html) and the [focusLost](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html) Event is triggered, I reset focus to the [Text Field](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html).
 
Via a [ModifyListener](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fevents%2FModifyListener.html) I check, if the entered String equals "" and if yes, a [fake tooltip](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/CreatefaketooltipsforitemsinaSWTtable.htm) is displayed, telling the User to enter something into the [Text Field](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html). 

The Problem is, if I have two Parts on a PartStack and the [Text Field](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html) is on my first Part, the User is still able to trigger a Part switch and work on the other Part without having to enter something into the [Text Field](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html) on the first Part first.

How is it possible to prohibit the User from switching between these Parts, as long as nothing is entered in the [Text Field](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html) on the first Part? 
I don´t want to hide Part 2, the App should still look the same, the user should just not be able to do anything until something has been entered into the [Text Field](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html).

Comment: So the focus out event isn't fired when you switch parts?

Comment: nope, just tested it again and it´s not send.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hide Part 2, then disable the widgets in that part instead. And display a message that asks the user to provide the necessary input back in Part 1. If the user does, hide that message and enable your widgets.

For example:

```
if (!isInputSatisfactory())
{
    displayMessage("Invalid input");
    myButton.setEnabled(false);
}
else
    myButton.setEnabled(true);
```